# How to tab through form elements using the enter key in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I know there are a couple of entries already dealing with this sort of problem and I have looked at quite a few, but none of then seem to work in my situation. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

What I have is a dynamically generated form (there can be a varied amount of inputs). I need to tab through them using my <kbd>enter</kbd> key. Currently the <kbd>tab</kbd> key tabs trough the elements fine, but my criteria requires me to enable the enter key. When I reach the final input and I press the enter, it needs execute the submit action that is currently done via an a tag

Below are code snippets of my HTML form as well as my JS that handles the `keypress` event

```
<div class="credential_form">
<div class="error_msg">
    <h4>There was a problem connecting.</h4>
</div>
<div class="credential_inputs">
    <div class="txt_wrapper">
        <input type="text" style="width: 130px">
    </div>
    <div class="txt_wrapper">
        <input type="password" style="width: 130px; display: none;" class="real">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="add_button">
    <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Add</span></a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="sub_input">
    <div class="link">
        <span class="sub_text">Forget your details? Go to&nbsp;</span>
        <a class="sub_link" href="http:somewhere.com">Somewhere</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

For some reason my collection variable does not recognize the current element in the if conditional.

```
var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

if (code == 13) {

var $inputs = $(event.target).closest('.credential_inputs').children($(':input:visible'));
var $addButton = $(event.target).closest('.credential_form').children($('a:first-child'));

if ( $(event.target) == $inputs[$inputs.length - 1] ) {
    $addButton.click()
} else {
    $(event.target).closest(".credential_inputs").nextAll('input:first').focus();
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For some reason I can't see where `length` is declared

Comment: @Alexander - My mistake, `length` should be `$inputs.length` as I'm trying to check if I'm at the final input in `$inputs`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) in your comparison.

```
if( $(event.target).is($inputs.last()) ) { ... }
```

Although, you might want to check your matching expression for your matched elements (`$inputs` and `$addButton`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find()` instead of children

```
var $inputs = $(event.target).closest('.credential_inputs').find(':input:visible');
```

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

This means that `$('.credential_inputs').children()` would only return your `.txt_wrapper` divs, and not traverse any further.

Comment: Thanks Brian, your answer has solved part of the problem as my variables now seem to contain the correct amount of elements, but I still can't get the tabbing to work as my condition doesn't seem to validate.